# Overwritten string in MIPS

Tags: assembly, mips, mars-simulator

I am making a quiz game where the questions are being printed out from external .txt files. From a certain point the questions start bleeding from the previous. I take that since the sizes of the questions are different, the buffer is overriden.
I saw some solutions where it is said to null terminate the string and/or empty the buffer, but I don't know how to do both.

Note also that I load the same buffer to every question and size stays the same throughout the entire code

```
.data

buffer: .space 1000
```

Comment: If you know how to do either one, then just do them both: zero the buffer ***before*** reusing it and null terminate ***after*** accepting input.  However, null termination alone should suffice, and we cannot tell you why it is not working for you without seeing your code.

Comment: A read-file system call should return an actual length.  `sb $zero` at that offset into your buffer to make a 0-terminated C string.